# SQL select for friendships table in cometchat

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Im beginner in sql soo i have big problem with this "big" select for friends table in cometchat. Can somebody write it for me.

Cometchat is configured for friends table :

```
friends

     toid     fromid
id    2          1
id    1          2
```

and sql select for it:

```
$sql = ("select DISTINCT ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." userid,         ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_NAME." username, 
".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." lastactivity, 
".DB_AVATARFIELD." avatar, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." link, 
cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status 
from ".TABLE_PREFIX."friends join ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE." on      ".TABLE_PREFIX."friends.toid = ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." left     join          cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." =     cometchat_status.userid ".DB_AVATARTABLE."
 where ".TABLE_PREFIX."friends.fromid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."' order by username asc");
return &sql;
```

My Rails app have friendships table :

```
friendships
     user_id     friend_id
id      1            2
id      2            1
```

When i just change order it does not work. I think that this is to hard for me right now. In rails i just check which friendship has a user_id of my profile and i show it friend_is as a friend.

THis is generated SQL for standard cometchat settings with friend table:

```
select DISTINCT users.id userid,
    users.name username, 
    users.current_sign_in_at lastactivity, 
    users.id  avatar,
    users.id link, 
    cometchat_status.message,
    cometchat_status.status 
  from friends 
  join users on friends.toid = users.id 
  left join cometchat_status on users.id = cometchat_status.userid
  where friends.fromid = '10'
  order by username asc
```

i try to change table from friends to my fiendships and toid (on friend_id) and formid( on user_id) and and vice versa but still it doesnt work and i do not get friends list.

Comment: could you add the rendered SQL instead of the badly formated code? You can take as much lines as you want -- same in your code -- and a query with just a few words on each line is very easier to read than a query with infinite lines

Comment: just add sql result in post

Comment: just formated it, isn't the word nicer when things are readable?

Comment: yes they are but i dont know how to do it.. hm now its even logic when i see it :)